# Device can be powered at 6V or 12V, which is better? Why?

Tags: power, voltage

I got [this camera](http://www.skywatcher.com/swtinc/product.php?id=177) and need to power it. Docs say that I can power it both at 6V and 12V, but laconically say also that it should be better to power it at lower voltage, so 6V.

Can anyone explain me why lower voltage is better?

Since I expect that power usage in both cases should be the same, I actually though that 12V should be better, because it needs a lower current. Am I missing something? Any clue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suspect there's an internal voltage regulator to regulate it to 5-6 volts. For compatibility, they added this voltage regulator so you can also power it with 6-14V. Internally, it's regulated to a lower voltage.

That would mean the voltage regulator dissipates half of the power in heat when you use 12V, and heat is bad (not only because it's a waste of energy, but also because it might harm other components). Therefore, a lower voltage would be better.

<sub>Disclaimer: I only *suspect* there's a voltage regulator inside, I don't actually know it.</sub>

Comment: This answer is what I would say, too: There's probably a linear voltage regulator in the camera, and higher voltages means it has to dissipate more power (generate heat.) If it were a switching regulator, there wouldn't be much difference in efficiency between the different voltages.

Comment: OK, seems reasonable. Since we are talking about an astronomy camera, and heat means noise and noise means less sensitivity, I think I'll power it at 6V. Thanks for your tips!